# In Flutter, can I automatically scroll to top of grid view without the user being able to cancel the scroll?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

In Flutter, I can use animateTo on the scroll controller to cause my grid view to scroll to zero offset over a set duration if I am some way down the view, but the animateTo method can be cancelled if the user does a scrolling action during the course of the scrolling to top animation (Notice in the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/animateTo.html) that it says 'An animation will be interrupted whenever the user attempts to scroll manually, or whenever another activity is started, or whenever the animation reaches the edge of the viewport and attempts to overscroll.'). Not only that, but if I put animateTo into an anonymous function for onTap in a GestureDetector, and then put a function right after it, that second function still gets executed even if the animateTo method is stopped because of the user doing a scrolling action before the animation finishes.

This is problematic for my situation. If the grid items are for written posts, I want the user to be able to click on the grid item, have the grid view scroll to top, fade out the grid view, and fade in content from the written post. Scrolling to the top before switching out the grid view for the content of the written post is important as I would like some header icons to animate and then disappear when the user scrolls some distance down, and for the header itself to move up after that header icon animation is triggered, resulting in more space for viewing content. To get the header icons back, the user would have to scroll up to a certain threshold, and then an appearance animation would play and the header icons would be back. So the user being able to cancel the animateTo method might result in those those icons not coming back when I want them to do so. BUT since the function right after the animateTo method still gets executed even if the animateTo method is cancelled, subsequent function(s) for fading out the grid view, removing its widget, replacing it with a new widget (that would have content from the written post), would still get executed (potentially leaving me with a new scroll controller at 0 but without those header icons??). Is there a way to scroll to the top of a grid view over a set duration (which duration would be set by a variable of mine that would change depending on the distance to be traveled in the scrolling to top) in a way that the user can NOT cancel? If there is no way to do this, then a consolation prize would be some way to prevent the subsequent function(s) for onTap of the Gesture Detector from being executed if the user stops the animateTo method from completing.

The jumpTo method will not work as it is not animated. I would have the name of my non-profit also shift and move as one scrolls down, so the icons getting back to an original position is also not the only thing dependent on scrolling back up.

Comment: use `IgnorePointer` as a parent to your grid view

Comment: I was not even aware of IgnorePointer. That sounds as if it may work. I will try IgnorePointer as a parent of the grid view or something further up the widget tree and see. Thank you so much!

Comment: your welcome, note that you don't have to add / remove it from the widget tree as it has `ignoring` parameter, so you can use `IgnorePointer(ignoring: scrollInProgress, ...` and simply change `scrollInProgress` variable

Comment: I tried using IgnorePointer last night, and it worked. Thank you! Can you put what you wrote in a response (rather than in comment(s)) so that I can accept it as a solution to what I wanted?

Comment: your welcome, feel free to post a self answer then :-)

Comment: btw if you post a self answer,  I would like to know how you managed to set `ignoring` book flag in sync with the controller

Comment: My own self answer is now posted, with my explanation of how I tried to sync IgnorePointer's boolean value with the scrolling to top duration. Let me know if it is not adequately clear. Thank you so much for your help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of comment(s) of @pskink, I was able to solve my problem with the use of `IgnorePointer`. I wrapped the screen Scaffold widget with `IgnorePointer`, set the ignoring value of `IgnorePointer` to the variable `scrollAnmInProgress`, set `scrollAnmInProgress` to true, did the scroll to top animation, and then set the `scrollAnmInProgress` value back to false. Here is some of the code that I used in the `onTap` method of the `GestureDetector`:

```
scrollAnmInProgress = true;
var scrollToTopTime = computeScrollToTopTime1(screenWidth,  _entriesGridScrollController.offset);
var scrollToTopTimeInt = scrollToTopTime.round();
controller.animateTo(0,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: scrollToTopTimeInt),
  curve: Curves.easeInOut);
var scrollAnmIgnorePointerTimer =
  Timer(Duration(milliseconds: scrollToTopTimeInt), () {
scrollAnmInProgress = false;});
```

The computeScrollToTopTime1 function was there to give me a duration time (whose value would depend on how much scrolling would have to be done) for the duration part of the `animateTo` method, which time was rounded to convert from a double type to the int type that is wanted by 'duration'. With that duration time in hand, I then started the scroll to top animation and I set a timer for the same time period as the duration of the `animateTo` method. When that timer was done (just at or around the time that the `animateTo` method finishes), the ignoring boolean value of `IgnorePointer` was set back to false, and the user could then scroll or do other things in the app. In the final app, I would likely call additional function(s) that would immediately set `IgnorePointer`'s ignoring boolean value back to true to have the user wait for the fading out of the content and the fading in of new content.

Comment: hmm, you didn't need to call `setState` when changing `scrollAnmInProgress` flag? also there is an easier way, my code was: `setState(() => ignoring = true); await controller.animateTo(...); setState(() => ignoring = false);` - note that the method you call that code must be `async` method

Comment: I thank you for providing your code, Pskink. I do have an _onScrollEvent that gets called when the Grid View scrolls, and it gets called even when the scrolling is being done by the animateTo method, so right up to around the end of the scroll to top animation, setState is repeatedly being called. This has worked for the most part, although there was one time when it seemed as if the IgnorePointer ignoring boolean value was not set back to false. After getting succesful attempt(s) before and after, I doubted whether it really failed or was not sure what to make of it for sure. But perhaps...

Comment: But perhaps the timer just usually reaches its allotted time for executing the switch of the ignoring value to false before the last scroll event of the animateTo method?? In that case, it would seem that my setup works, but would, in rare cases, open the possibility to the timer's switch of the boolean ignoring value happening after the last scroll event of the animateTo method, leaving the user in the bad spot of not being able to interact with the app at all and thus it basically being a dead app to the user at that point, at least if the app is not stopped? That would not be ideal if so.

Comment: As for your code, keep in mind that I am a newbie to dart and flutter trying to stumble my way through developing an app without any coworkers to help. Futures and asynchronous functions are still an area where I am not completely comfortable and where I have more to learn and where I need a stronger conceptual grasp. I would like to learn that, especially if I would like to get a part-time position in software development down the road to help fund my non-profit and give me funds to provide for a (hoped and prayed for) wife and family.

Comment: (oh, clarification for above, if it was not adequately clear. The _onScrollEvent method referred to above calls setState. Hence, setState gets repeatedly called when the animateTo method's scrolling happens.

Comment: yeas, but that way `setState` is called on every animation frame... (every few pixels your grid view is scrolled) - you should call it only when it's really needed, otherwise the performance could suffer

Comment: In other situations, that would make sense. In my case, I am wanting to emulate the functionality of header content changing depending on scroll position (that can be seen on the CredibleFaith.org site). There, for much of the spread from scroll offset zero to 1,000, there is some item in the header that is affected by scroll position. So, at least in my case, it seems that setState does need to be called for much of the process of the animateTo method's scrolling up. If everything is fixed in place by scroll offset 1,000, perhaps I could put in a conditional to not call setState above 1,000.

Comment: why don't you use slivers then? for example `SliverPersistentHeader` - in any case, try removing the `Timer` and simply use `await controller.animateTo(...)` instead

Comment: I went to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html and tried the sliverapp bar example setup that they have, and its base settings can not replicate the functionality of the aforementioned website. That site does not immediately scroll the header up as soon as one starts scrolling down, but the SliverAppBar does. I prefer the website's waiting for the user to scroll down some distance before taking away header icons and giving more space to the mainstage for content that the user would like to see. Unless SliverAppBar can do that, I would prefer the current approach.

Comment: As for using await instead of a timer, this TutorialsPoint dart programming async page has the following: 'An asynchronous operation executes in a thread, separate from the main application thread. When an application calls a method to perform an operation asynchronously, the application can continue executing while the asynchronous method performs its task.' I want to have a series of functions called one after the other (something like 1. scrollToTop(), 2. fadeContentOut(), 3. switchMainstageWidget, 4. FadeWidgetIn), and I want the second function to wait for the completion of the first.

Comment: The link for 'this TutorialsPoint dart programming async page is https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_async.htm.

Comment: My understanding of the working of the async function is that, if the above functions were my setup, marking the scrollToTop function as async would result in function 2 getting executed immediately rather than waiting for the scrollToTop function to finish first. I don't want that. But if I don't mark it as async, but put await for the animateTo method, I get a VSCode warning 'The await expression can only be used in an async function. Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'.' Hence your 'note that the method you call that code must be async method'.

Comment: As for your wondering about a custom scroll position and using hold, I am not sure. I confess to not fully understanding how to implement that to test it and see if it would work, and as IgnorePointer does work for me, I may just stick with IgnorePointer for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to play devil's advocate here with an answer you may not like. You could use `IgnorePointer` or such to prevent user interaction while you're performing a scroll which should solve your immediate problem, but that seems... tangential to the actual problem.

The problem as I see it is that you're trying to manually animate a ton of different things that will result in a hugely complicated app that is very fragile and potentially user-unfriendly. If there's **ever** a bunch of animations that a user might want to manually cancel by scrolling in your app, there's a good chance those animations don't belong.

If you do animate as described this could result in very difficult to diagnose bugs (e.g. what happens when the app is closed mid-scroll), weird scenarios, and a bunch of potential pitfalls that aren't immediately apparent. The example that comes to mind first is what would happen if the user immediately presses back from the written post - if you've manually animated each step of the "to the post" animation, for a good UX you should probably animate the "from the post" animation as well, which sounds like it could be pretty complicated.

What I'd recommend is simplifying the UX of the app to the bare minimum - simple animations, full-page fade-in and fade-out, etc, unless there's a *huge* need for a custom animation. From my experience 99% of users *will simply not care* if there are fancy animations so long as the app functions well. Get things working first, and then if you have tons of extra time on your hands, then you can play with more custom animations. As a developer, I sometimes fall into this trap too, but experience has taught me that people use apps because they *work*, not because they have fancy animations.

Now, if you feel like you really do need some animations of icons, footers, headers, etc, I'd recommend you lean on the built-in [hero](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/animations/hero-animations) animations as they're very simple to use and surprisingly functional, and if needed you could use a package such as [flutter villains](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_villains) that enables additional animations post-page-render. And if you need headers that appear and disappear with scrolling, flutter has a mechanism in that with [flutter slivers](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/advanced/slivers). Combine slivers with heroes, and you should be able to make an app that has fancy animation behaviour without explicitly defining animations paths all over the place, which IMO is much more in the spirit of flutter.

Comment: Hello, McKenzie! Thank you for taking so much time to respond. Just to give some reference for what I am trying to achieve, I love much of the look and functionality of the CredibleFaith.org website and am trying to imitate much of its look and functionality in the app that I am working on. I am seeking to use no routes at all in my flutter app. I want one frame to a mainstage area and content in the mainstage area just gets swapped in and out. Navigate around that website if you would like to see what I am going for. As for some other things... (character limit)

Comment: I think that at least some of what you are pointing out would have a lot more force for me in a work context in which time is money and my spending lots of time on animations or other things would be viewed by my employer as unnecessary. I do value my time, but I also am working alone, having gone through much of a Udemy course on Dart and Flutter earlier in the year, with no computer science degree of any type. I do have a lot of background of having done most of the javascript, html, css, and php coding for websites that I developed, so this endeavor is not completely foreign to me.

Comment: I had not considered the back button issue, as my plan to note use routes meant that I would not get automatic back buttons in the apps. I just assumed that the user would not see any back button at all in my app, and so that use case did not occur to me (and I am not sure that there will be a back button anywhere in the app....does Android automatically provide the user with one?). This is the only place where I expect to use IgnorePointer for preventing the cancelling of an animation.

Comment: As for closing the app mid-scroll, is the problem in that case that the undo pointer 'ignoring' boolean value would never be set back to false, and thus that when the user would enter the app again, the user would not be able to use the app for everything to which the IgnorePointer applied?

Comment: Given that I do not plan to use routes, I was not certain that hero animations would be of any use. Isn't it true that a hero animation takes a widget from one route and animates it to the new position on a different route? If that is what happens, then my use of no routes might mean that hero animations be useless to me (feel free to correct me if I am wrong on that, I am relatively new to flutter).

Comment: Hmm. Okay, if you're trying to replicate your website's exact UX, I can see how some of my advice might be less valid. Hmm. My degree in UX tells me to dislike your website, but I do genuinely respect what you're going for. And my apologies for my turn of phrase, I hope claiming devil's advocate caused no offence. However, I would still argue that using routes could make your website easier to reproduce in flutter - maybe not pixel for pixel, but by defining _what_ you want to see, rather than _how_ I think you could build out similar functionality in a way quicker and simpler way.

Comment: For example, if your header was wrapped as a hero, you could include the same code in each page and then when transitions happened it would stay as-is, and  you could use flutter_villains to make it so the actual content of the page animated after the transition, similar to how content appears after transition in your website. The only thing you’d been losing would be the initial scroll up, but you’d be gaining back-button functionality (which every android has in the back button or back gesture depending on version), which is something that I would consider missing from your website

Comment: Plus writing the code in flutter would become... simpler. I'd still recommend using routes for a couple reasons - the first being that you could deep link from your website and the second being that if you wanted to, you could use flutter to actually build out your website if you get to the point of having more functionality through the app than in the current website (although for now flutter does still produce pages that are fairly large and would be slow loading). But I'd agree that with your different constraints including time, you have different constraints, so feel free to ignore me =).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, McKenzie. There was no problem in using the phrase you did. You could level very harsh criticisms and insults, and I would likely not be bothered by it. In regard to that website, one thing that I like about it (if it were an app) would be that one would not easily get lost. I have looked at layouts of lots of different apps, and I hate how a lot of them are set up, such that one has various ways to get to different parts of the app.

Comment: If the design question is, ‘How can a user quickly know & see all the content available in the app?’, the setup of that website as an app would make it relatively easy compared to other apps. Other apps segregate content into various screens and categories, & the user is left with no way to see all the content in one place & with basic questions unanswered. Does content in this category overlap with content in other categories? Is the content behind this category going to be more interesting to me than a different one? Content in the format of that website would avoid a lot of that problem.

Comment: (Stackoverflow giving me 'Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?')... As for routes, when I did much of the Udemy course, it was evident that a lot of widgets could result in having to pass data along from widget to widget to widget in the tree, and I did not want to do too much of that. If I had a set home screen area and swapped out mainstage widgets in the app, I could have a relatively flat structure without having to pass data through too many levels. Perhaps I could do something similar with routes.

Comment: Your two points in favor of using routes are worth considering. I never even thought about deep linking from a website to the app. If routes let me deep link to a website and my current approach did not, that would be a point in favor of routes. If the Flutter app equaled a website in every respect and then surpassed it in terms of look and functionality, and if that required routes, that would also favor routes. As it is, I have no plans to have my Flutter codebase be used for replacing a website. Also, I admit that back button functionality would also be a point in favor of routes.